# How to print html code snippets in the html view

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails and I want to show some well-formatted HTML code snippets to the user on my website. Just like we can do it on Github. I know showing code snippet with Markdown is such a breeze, but I am struggling to do it in the HTML file.

Is there a way to do this?

I know this is not RoR specific, still is there any gem that will help me display source code in the view?

Thanks.

Comment: How about just using the `<pre>` tag?

Comment: If you can implement JavaScript, Google's **[Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)** is fast, free, and easy to use.

Comment: @DrydI was just using `<code>` tag I think I will try `<pre>`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap options are pretty nice as well. They provide tags for code, user input, variables, and sample output.